# Virtual Object in QTP 9.5

Tags: qtp

How to use Virtual Object from Virtual Object manager? I am using QTP version 9.5
I have added required Object into Virtual Object Collections. And how to add it to Object Repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In contrary to what you are used to with Microsoft products, the Help function in QTP is rather good. Try to hit the F1 button some time!

Use of Virtual Object:
`Print Window("My Window").VirtualObject("My Virtual Object").ToString()`

Comment: Is it possible to add it into Object Repository?

Comment: Create your VObjects with the radiobutton setting "Identify object using" to "Entire parent hierarchy". When you record a test, the Virtual Object is automatically recognized and added to the Object Repository. I did not find a way to add them to the repository without recording, but you can always create a copy of a formerly recorded Virtual Object and change the test object details to your demands. The drawback is that the copied VO is not displayed in your VO manager.